# My Java Process taking more heap memeory than max heap memory defined

Tags: java

My current min and Max heap memory is 1-4 GB but If I check heap memory utilization in Linux(Redhat) host, showing me 5+ GB heap memory.

It must through Out Of Memory Exception due to Heap memory over but unfortunately it is running over the Heap Memory not getting any exception.

Comment: How are you checking it? (command? which part of the output?)

Comment: You need to provide evidence of how your are setting the maxima and what you mean by "check heap memory utilization" including tools and the specific values

Comment: You seem to think that Java heap memory == process heap memory, but that is not the case. Java heap memory is where the Java objects are stored, Java itself requires additional memory for things like class definitions, garbage collection metadata, and native memory (e.g. direct ByteBuffers), and things like thread stacks.